# sharing data between controllers (persistent)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have two different views, each one with its own controller, in the first view I want to retrieve the data I write in a input text and when I click the submit button, load the second view with the data retrieved from the first one.

I could made that works with a service, displaying the data in the second view but after refreshing the page, there's nothing there anymore.

Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
Application.service("checkingcity", function($rootScope, $timeout){
  var city = {};
  city.data = false;
  city.sendData = function(data){
    this.data = data;
    $timeout(function(){
         $rootScope.$broadcast('data_shared');
      },100);
  };
  city.getData = function(){
    return this.data;
  };
  return city;
});
```

The controller to retrieve the data from the input text on the first view:

```
Application.controller("ControllerOne", function($scope, checkingcity){

  $scope.checkCity = function(){
    if($scope.City){
           checkingcity.sendData($scope.City);
         }
         else{
           alert("No data");
          }
   }
});
```

Second controller that reads the data from the first view/controller:

```
Application.controller("ControllerTwo", function($scope, checkingcity){

    $scope.town = '';
    $scope.$on('data_shared',function(){
            var town =  checkingcity.getData();
        $scope.town = town;

    });

});
```

Comment: I'm really surprised one or more of the duplicates didnt' pop up when you were writing this question. As you're writing your title, duplicates should populate; when that happens, please click through each duplicate to ensure your question hasn't already been answered.

Comment: When you say refreshing the page, do you mean refreshing the browser page/tab as a whole?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker that's what I did, that's why I am writing here. Anyways thanks for the link, is not my case but I have a clearer idea now.

Comment: @DanielNalbach Yes, refreshing the browser.

Comment: @Panconjugo - Angular apps are reloaded and reinitialized on browser refresh. Unless you store data in a cookie before refresh and retrieve it after refresh, everything is lost.

Comment: @DanielNalbach Thanks for your response, I knew that that happen when  an angularjs app is reloaded but I thought there was an angularjs solution for that. Anyways, thanks so much, Im gonna do it using cookies :)